# How to force return value to be same type as argument value in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

If I have a function which accepts an argument of multiple types, how can I enforce that the return must match the value of the input?

This comes up particularly when I want a method to work with any children of a parent type. For demonstration, consider something that is "barlike":

```
abstract struct Barlike
  property bar: Int32
  def initialize(@bar); end
  end
  abstract def make_clang_sound
  abstract def serve_drinks
end
```

Now any struct can implement those two methods, and store that value

```
struct Bar1 < Barlike
  def make_clang_sound
    puts "bing bang bong"
  end

  def serve_drinks
    puts "your drink sir"
  end
end

struct Bar2 < Barlike
  def make_clang_sound
    puts "kling klang"
  end

  def serve_drinks
    puts "here are your drinks"
  end
end
```

Now what if I have a method that wants to use the bar and return a new one with an updated value (these are structs afterall):

```
def foo(arg : Barlike)
  new_bar = arg.bar + 2
  arg.class.new(new_bar)
end
```

this will return a `Bar1` if a `Bar1` is passed in and a `Bar2` if that is passed in but it's not guaranteed:

```
def foo(arg : Barlike)
  "howdy"
end
```

I'm going to be putting my `foo` into an abstract structure as well, so I need to guarantee that implementers of `foo` return the same type of `Barlike` that was given.

I tried

```
def foo(arg : Barlike) : arg.class
end
```

But that's a compile time error (arg cannot be used there like that)

I also tried

```
def foo(arg : Barlike) : typeof(arg)
end
```

which passes, but typeof here is just Barlike whereas I really need it to be only the thing that was passed in, only Bar1 or Bar2 and so on.

Can macros help?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to restrict it  to the subtype, after all `Barlike` is your interface and also  fine as an input restriction apparently, why not as an output  restriction?

Comment: I tried to create an example divorced from my specific case hoping that would help me think more generally. In my specific case, I wanted my method to accept both a Tuple with 3 numeric elements, and an array of numeric elements and call them both "vectorlike". Thus I expected the method to return an array or a tuple depending on what was passed in. As you point out in your answer, this eventually starts to smell and isn't a great pattern. The interface should be in charge, but I'm very glad to have learned about free variables!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool for this are [free variables](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/type_restrictions.html#free-variables). That's essentially generics scoped to a single method.

```
# This method returns the same type as its argument
def foo(arg : T) : T forall T
  arg
end
```

This would already solve the main part of your question.

However, it is currently not possible to apply type restrictions to free variables, for example restricting `T` to `Barlike`.

There are workarounds, though:

1. Use a macro to validate the argument type:

```
def foo(arg : T) : T forall T
  {% raise "arg must implement Barlike" unless T < Barlike %}
  arg
end
```

2. Delegate to another method with a type restriction:

```
def foo(arg : T) : T forall T
  foo_impl(arg)
end

private def foo_impl(arg : Barlike)
  arg
end
```

Both workarounds affect the implementation of the method. There is no way to specify such a type restriction for a `abstract def`. Number 2 might be feasible, if you make `foo_impl` abstract and require inheriting classes to implement this one, instead of `foo`.
But it's probably also fine to just go with the initial example using free variables, without the `Barlike` restriction. In practice, you probably don't gain much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that works:

```
{% for sub in Barlike.subclasses %}
  struct {{sub}}
    def foo() : {{sub}}
      {{sub}}.new(@bar+1)
    end
  end
{% end %}
```

[full example](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/6y5r)

But it feels like this is trying to solve the wrong problem. It uses the `#subclasses` macro to generate a foo for all of the child structs.

You could also declare these as self methods inside the abstract class: [example](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/6y5u).

Comment: Please include relevant examples directly in your answers. Readers should be able to understand it directly on SO. Links are great for more details.

Comment: +1 to what Johannes Müller said, and thanks for pointing out the `subclasses` macro, that is actually a decent fit for some use cases.